Disabling logging by ElasticScaleControllerExtension for Azure Function App
Our Azure Function Apps run in an Elastic Premium plan.  Roughly every 15 seconds the ElasticScaleControllerExtension seems to spew 2 log entries:
Executing HTTP request: {
  "requestId": "6b573bc8-ab9b-4640-aa55-b260e91992a8",
  "method": "GET",
  "userAgent": "ElasticScaleControllerExtension/2.0.28.0",
  "uri": "/admin/host/ping"
}

and
Executed HTTP request: {
  "requestId": "6b573bc8-ab9b-4640-aa55-b260e91992a8",
  "identities": "",
  "status": "200",
  "duration": "4"
}

I'd like to suppress these log entries I use a lot of function apps and we're trying to reduce the amount of useless log entries to find the significant ones faster and to avoid limits on how many log entries are collected by our monitoring service on a daily basis.
Based on reading a number of posts, we came up with this host.json file:
{
  "functionTimeout": "20:00:00",
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "None",
      "Function": "Warning",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Error",
      "Host.Function.Console": "Information",
      "Function.Heartbeat": "None",
      "Function.HttpStart.User": "Information",
      "Function.TimerStart.User": "Information",
      "Function.ExportSequence.User": "Information",
      "Function.ExportTable.User": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}

Unfortunately we've had no luck suppressing the log entries listed above.  Any useful suggestions would be appreciated.

Did you ever figure this out? We are experiencing similar issues.

No, sorry, we still have this issue.  Hopefully someone else will have a suggestion.
